# LDU matrix decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition

Let $A$ be a matrix that can be written as $LDU$ for some lower unitriangular matrix $L$, some diagonal matrix $D$ and some upper unitriangular matrix $U$.
Then, are the eigenvalues of $A$ the same as those of $D$? Are the eigenvalues of $A$ the elements on the diagonal of $D$?

Comment: Matrix diagonalization is expressed by $A=PDP^{-1}$. You don't necessarily have $U=L^{-1}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessarily.  Consider [this example:](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Eigenvalues%20of%20%7B%7B1%2C0%7D%2C%7B1%2C1%7D%7D*%7B%7B2%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C3%7D%7D*%7B%7B1%2C1%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%7D%7D)
$$
\pmatrix{
1&0\\
1&1
}
\pmatrix{
2&0\\
0&3
}
\pmatrix{
1&1\\
0&1
} = 
\pmatrix{
2&2\\
2&5
}
$$
which has eigenvalues $1$ and $6$.

Comment: ok.  Is it at least true that D is positive definite (i.e., its diagonal elements are positive), if A is?

Comment: @Matteo actually, yes! If $A$ is (symmetric) positive definite, then the LDU factorization amounts to the same as the [Cholesky decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition#Symmetric_positive_definite_matrices), and so we will necessarily have a $U = V^T$ scenario.

Comment: I was in need of this fact to prove the existence of Cholesky decomposition.  So, how to prove the positivity of D without appelling to Cholesky?

Comment: @Matteo that's an unusual way of doing things; normally you use $QR$ factorization to prove Cholesky.  In any case, do you have the uniqueness of LDU factorizations?

Comment: @Matteo or, are you aware of either the Schur or spectral decomposition of a matrix?

Comment: The spectral decomposition.  The spectral theorem says that every symmetric real matrix $A$ has an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors.  If we call $N$ the matrix whose diagonals are these eigenvectors, then we have that $N^{-1}AN=N^tAN$ is a diagonal matrix $D$ (whose values are the eigenvalues), so we can decompose A in $A=NDN^t$.  Right?